# How to deny HTTP POST requests from other applications?

Tags: c#, .net, iis

I am doing security checks on my web application which hosted in .net IIS  , I comes to know that there is a possibility to access my web pages through HTTP Post method from any other application ,  we need to deny those requests which comes through HTTP POST method, Is there a any possible way to deny this?

From the below example of code **'www.example.com'** is my website , and 'recepticle.aspx' is a web page which accessed from other web application **(eg: www.Hacker1.com)** through HttpClient, how I can prevent this?

### **Code written on (www.Hacker1.com)**

```
private static readonly HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);
var response = client.PostAsync("http://www.example.com/recepticle.aspx", content);
var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

I need to deny HTTP POST requests from other web applications to my web pages , but I can allow requests from browser

Comment: May I know what technology and platform are you using on your server side?

Comment: if you are using Authorizing system such as asp.net identity. just put [Authorize(Roles="Admin or role you want to allow")] as an attribute on post method that should make it fine

Comment: Assuming "any other application" means any other application there is no way. If you can narrow down your requirements it may become answerable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only deny POST request for everyone - you can't deny them selectively. Any protection you'll put in place (like checking referrer) hacker site can easily mock. Proper protection is forcing authentication of users and allow only authenticated user to make such request.

I.E. Have endpoint login.aspx - exchange username/password for authentication cookie/or token and recepticle.aspx should check if the authentication cookie/token is present.

BTW. Authentication topic is complex and ASP.NET/IIS has lot of templates build-in. Still its easy to do it wrong. So if you're unsure it is best to delegate authentication to OAUTH / use one of big providers you trust https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_OAuth_providers

Comment: Thanks Ondrej , I got your point , in this case if HTTPClient has used in console application , receiver server considering the request from which browser (IE or Mozila or Chrome) ?

Comment: @Rajeshkanna.S - browser identifies itself with so called user agent string; this is known http header. However this can be simply mocked like httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.113 Safari/537.36"); - now server will think your console app is chrome browser.

Comment: Okay, Thanks Ondrej.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to block your requests based on any parameter on request which in your case is `HTTP verbs`, Easily you can do it on IIS through [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/manage/configuring-security/configure-request-filtering-in-iis)

Comment: Thanks Mohamman, I added more information on my question , please have a look .

Answer (score 0):

You can deny POST requests, but there's no sensible way -- without adding authentication -- to tell which application those requests are coming from, which means that you won't be able to allow POST requests from just your client app, but no others.

Just secure the endpoint properly by using some sort of authentication.

If your endpoints are only supposed to be accessed by your application, why are you making them publicly-accessible in the first place? If this is the *same* application, just call the functions directly. If this is a separate application, use firewall rules to make sure it can only be accessed by localhost (e.g.).

Answer (score -1):

You can define the specific origin in web config from where request you want to authorize.
You can define http protocol for your application in web config like this

```
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type, Authorization, Set-Authorization" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Expose-Headers" value="Set-Authorization" />
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

Here this code example contains * for Origin value that means it will allow for all application request so you have to pass the your application url here instead of *.